# How to make header normal font in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

The moderncv (classic) consists of various sections like address, phone, email .. in header which are italic! How do I change them to normal font?

[image]

So, I want to change the above italic data into normal font

The template can be found here: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/moderncv-cv-and-cover-letter

Comment: [Welcome to SE.TeX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please expand your question by adding a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: The use of a MWE is to give LaTeX code that someone could copy/paste and modify to answer to your question. So image is nice but LaTeX code is more important (having both is perfect). Without your code I can't modify it in order to delete the italic.

Comment: @ppr I have given the template link above thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the definition of the `classic` style, contained in `moderncvstyleclassic.sty` you will find all the macros that control the appearance of the elements of the document. For fonts you'll find:

```
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}
```

The one you are trying to alter is `\addressfont` so putting

```
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries}
```

in your preamble should do what you want.

Comment: Well that's just the address.. How about \phone, \email, \homepage ?

Comment: If you look into the definition of `\makecvtitle` you'll see that `\addressfont` is the font which is installed for the whole block of text containing your personal info in the title. Have you tried the solution on your document?

Comment: I actually overwritten some elements with \normalfont after removing its working.. thanks

Comment: @iamlol if you are happy with the solution please consider accepting it as an answer